# Replace get_the_title and the_exerpt with custom arrays

Tags: get-the-title

Here is the code in home.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="pikachoose">
    <ul id="pikame" >
        <?php

$cat1 = stripslashes(get_option('lx_feat_cat'));

//The Query
query_posts('category_name='. $cat1 . '&showposts=9');
//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$link = get_permalink( $post->ID );
?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $link ?>">
        <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-home');
            } 
        ?></a>
        <div class="slide">
        <?php $slide_title = get_the_title(); ?>
        <h1 class="title-slider clean"><?php _e($slide_title, lexington-theme); ?></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
        </li>



 <?php endwhile; endif;
//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to replace get_the_title with a custom title and a custom the_exerpt for each slide. I figure I could create two arrays with my custom titles and exerpts and pull those instead of the ones from the database:

```
<?php
$get_the_title() = "Custom title 1";
    $get_the_title() = "Custom title 2";
    $get_the_title() = "Custom title 3";

etc for 9 slides..

    $the_excerpt() = "Custom exerpt 1";
    $the_excerpt() = "Custom exerpt 2";

etc...
```

My angle was replacing $get_the_title() with $get_the_title_custom[$link] but no luck. Not being that skilled in php, I cannot figure out how to do it without breaking something. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you dont assign value to a function, you pass arguments to it

Comment: Please could you give me an example using the above code as I am not a skilled coder, more of an "edit a few lines here and there" person :p By all means let me know if what I am trying to do is complicated and I should move on..

Comment: what you actually want to achieve ? if you just want to replce title and excerpt with custom , then well then just do it by replacing them by your custom title , why you need to assign values to wordpress function ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of arrays to hold the custom titles and excerpts keyed to the post IDs. In this example, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88 and 99 are sample post IDs.

```
$slides = array(
    11 => array(
        'title'   => 'Custom title 1',
        'excerpt' => 'Custom excerpt 1',
    ),
    22 => array(
        'title'   => 'Custom title 2',
        'excerpt' => 'Custom excerpt 2',
    ),
    33 => array(
        'title'   => 'Custom title 3',
        'excerpt' => 'Custom excerpt 3',
    ),
    44 => array(
        'title'   => 'Custom title 4',
        'excerpt' => 'Custom excerpt 4',
    ),
    55 => array(
        'title'   => 'Custom title 5',
        'excerpt' => 'Custom excerpt 5',
    ),
    66 => array(
        'title'   => 'Custom title 6',
        'excerpt' => 'Custom excerpt 6',
    ),
    77 => array(
        'title'   => 'Custom title 7',
        'excerpt' => 'Custom excerpt 7',
    ),
    88 => array(
        'title'   => 'Custom title 8',
        'excerpt' => 'Custom excerpt 8',
    ),
    99 => array(
        'title'   => 'Custom title 9',
        'excerpt' => 'Custom excerpt 9',
    ),
);
```

Instead of using `get_the_title()` use `$slides[$post->ID]['title']`.
Instead of `the_excerpt()` use `echo $slides[$post->ID]['excerpt']`.